# How to reset iput file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I got a big form, and I need Reset function. I wrote some code, which work nice, but I have only trouble with input[type=file]. I readed I have to delete it from DOM and replace with copy ofit, but then, I cant send this file anymore! I m sending form data via ajax, and file field is require. So, before reset form , all send fine, but after reset server response I didnt send file ._.
I pretty sure trouble exactly with input[type=file], because before I added this functional my reset func worked fine.
I tried this code:
      `var imguploadcont = form_tool.find(".imguploadcont");
      imguploadcont.html('<input id="imgInp_{{key}}" type="file" name="userfile" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile"><label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">'+imguploadcont.attr('text')+'</label>');`

And this: 
     `var fileinput = form_tool.find("input[type=file]");
      fileinput.val('');
      form_tool.find('.custom-file-label').text('Choose image');`

Whats wrong?

Comment: There's no need to delete and recreate it just to reset the value.

Comment: @YakutD Primarily the issue is in your code. You have used **id** attribute twice for **input[type=file]**

Also, you need to bind your AJAX Submit code correctly. 

$("#form_id).on("submit",function(){ .... your ajax code... });

Comment: @Alpha, thanks, I fixed, but still cant send file after reset field._.

Comment: Are you using serialize option of jQuery AJAX ?

Do you see the parameter **userfile** being sent with values ?

If your AJAX submit is placed under $(document).ready(function(){ . .. });

Place it inside $(function() {

.. place the submit code here as your form content has changed dynamically.. 

});

Answer (score 1):

For General Understanding, if your body content has been changed **dynamically via AJAX or any other method and particularly you are using using  elements to re-submit the same**. You need to bind the function's submit as follows -

```
    $(function()
    {

    .. Place your code here .. This is irrespective of document contents loaded or modified just before initially or re-submit based on dynamically loaded elements.

$("#form_id").on("submit",function(e)
{
e.preventDefault(); // Prevents default submission of the form

$.ajax({ // Your AJAX Code // });

});    

 });
```

Below method won't work as your DOM content has been changed and it considers only loaded values (not dynamically modified elements)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
.. Your functions ...

});
```

Comment: @YakutD You should upvote and Select my Reply as the Answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this line to clear the file value

```
$('.custom-file-input').val(null);
```